# How to stop frames per second from dropping?

Tags: java, android, performance, game-engine

Okay, so why would my frames per second drop at a random time while playing the game? and what can I do to fix it.  Below im going to show the code that I have with the engine that was built.

```
        public Engine() {
    Log.d("Engine","Engine constructor");
    p_view = null;
    p_canvas = null;
    p_thread = null;
    p_running = false;
    p_paused = false;
    p_resume = false;
    p_paintDraw = null;
    p_paintFont = null;
    p_numPoints = 0;
    p_typeface = null;
    p_preferredFrameRate = 40;
    p_sleepTime = 1000 / p_preferredFrameRate;
    p_pauseCount = 0;
    p_group = new LinkedList<Sprite>();
}

   /**
 * Runnable.run thread method (MAIN LOOP)
 */
@Override 
public void run() {
    Log.d("Engine","Engine.run start");

    ListIterator<Sprite> iter=null, iterA=null, iterB=null;    

    Timer frameTimer = new Timer();
    int frameCount=0;
    int frameRate=0;
    long startTime=0;
    long timeDiff=0;

    while (p_running) {
        // Process frame only if not paused
        if (p_paused) continue;

        // Calculate frame rate
        frameCount++;
        startTime = frameTimer.getElapsed();
        if (frameTimer.stopwatch(1000)) {
            frameRate = frameCount;
            frameCount = 0;

            //reset touch input count
            p_numPoints = 0;
        }


        // Call abstract update method in sub-class
        update();


        /**
         * Test for collisions in the sprite group.
         * Note that this takes place outside of rendering.
         */
        iterA = p_group.listIterator();
        while (iterA.hasNext()) {
            Sprite sprA = (Sprite)iterA.next();
            if (!sprA.getAlive()) continue;
            if (!sprA.getCollidable()) continue;

            /*
             * Improvement to prevent double collision testing
             */
            if (sprA.getCollided()) 
                continue; //skip to next iterator

            //iterate the list again
            iterB = p_group.listIterator(); 
            while (iterB.hasNext()) {
                Sprite sprB = (Sprite)iterB.next();
                if (!sprB.getAlive()) continue;
                if (!sprB.getCollidable()) continue;

                /*
                 * Improvement to prevent double collision testing
                 */
                if (sprB.getCollided()) 
                    continue; //skip to next iterator

                //do not collide with itself
                if (sprA == sprB) continue;

                /*
                 * Ignore sprites with the same ID? This is an important
                 * consideration. Decide if your game requires it or not.
                 */
                if (sprA.getIdentifier() == sprB.getIdentifier())
                    continue;

                if (collisionCheck(sprA, sprB)) {
                    sprA.setCollided(true);
                    sprA.setOffender(sprB);
                    sprB.setCollided(true);
                    sprB.setOffender(sprA);
                    break; //exit while
                }
            }
        }


        // begin drawing
        if (beginDrawing()) {

            // Call abstract draw method in sub-class
            draw();


            /**
             * Draw the group entities with transforms
             */
            iter = p_group.listIterator(); 
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                Sprite spr = (Sprite)iter.next();
                if (spr.getAlive()) {
                    spr.animate();
                    spr.draw();
                }
            }

            /**
             * Print some engine debug info.
             */
            int x = p_canvas.getWidth()-150;
            p_canvas.drawText("ENGINE", x, 20, p_paintFont);
            p_canvas.drawText(toString(frameRate) + " FPS", x, 40, 
                p_paintFont);
            p_canvas.drawText("Pauses: " + toString(p_pauseCount), 
                x, 60, p_paintFont);

            // done drawing
            endDrawing();
        }

        /*
         * Do some cleanup: collision notification, removing
         * 'dead' sprites from the list.
         */
        iter = p_group.listIterator(); 
        Sprite spr = null;
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            spr = (Sprite)iter.next();

            //remove from list if flagged
            if (!spr.getAlive()) {
                iter.remove();
                continue;
            }

            //is collision enabled for this sprite?
            if (spr.getCollidable()) {

                //has this sprite collided with anything?
                if (spr.getCollided()) {

                    //is the target a valid object?
                    if (spr.getOffender() != null) {

                        /*
                         * External func call: notify game of collision
                         * (with validated offender)
                         */
                        collision(spr);

                        //reset offender
                        spr.setOffender(null);
                    }

                    //reset collided state
                    spr.setCollided(false);

                }
            }
        }

        // Calculate frame update time and sleep if necessary
        timeDiff = frameTimer.getElapsed() - startTime;
        long updatePeriod = p_sleepTime - timeDiff;
        if (updatePeriod > 0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep( updatePeriod ); // i notice this is called when frames are low
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e) {}
        }

    }//while
    Log.d("Engine","Engine.run end");
    System.exit(RESULT_OK);
}    


    public void setFrameRate(int rate) {
    p_preferredFrameRate = rate;
    p_sleepTime = 1000 / p_preferredFrameRate;
}
```

So this is not the entire engine, but it is everything that deals with the frames  Why is it randomly dropping? What I am noticing that thread.sleep is being called when the frames drop below 15.  I am using a nexus 5 to test this running on android 4.4.2, and My question here is How do I stop the frames from dropping that low and having it sleep especially after calling a recreate(); method when you lose the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take out the Thread.Sleep statement altogether. Or just pass "0" into the Sleep call (if you are trying to yield cycles to other threads and processes).  On each cycle of the run() loop, calculate how much time actually elapsed and update your simulation based on this value. In other words, don't try to force a hard-coded frame rate.

The device has an upperbound on frame rate (60fps on my device). So you'll likely be sleeping a little during each loop anyway.

Comment: So removing the tread.sleep statement will stop the frames from dropping?

Comment: Try it and see... if it doesn't, you should apply a profiling tool to your code.

Comment: So i actually took out the sleep method and it turns out its still crashing.  Whats happening now is that its freezing when too many pictures are loading.